# MongoDB ODBC configuration for MongoDB BI Connector

Tags: mongodb, tableau-api, powerbi-desktop, mongodb-biconnector

I’m trying to setup MongoDB BI Connector to use it for Tableau. I have already running mongosqld and it is connecting successfully from windows cmd to aws documentdb, but when I try to setup MongoDB ODBC Data Source it shows Connection failed [MongoDB][ODBC 1.4(w) Driver] can’t connect to MySQL server on ‘xxxxx’. The same error is when trying unicode or ansi. It is also not working connecting directly from Tableau Desktop using MongoDB BI Connector. Same error message. I'm using port 3307. Perhaps anyone has had the same issue and can advise how to solve it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I already found a solution by myself.